# Return true or false from laravel to Angularjs $scope

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I'm trying to return true or false from Laravel to a $scope directive in Angularjs. This is the laravel code that is called:

```
public function check() {
    return Response::json(Auth::check());
}
```

This is the service that queries Laravel:

```
app.factory('UserService', ['$http', '$location', function($http, $location) {

    return {
        loggedIn: function() {

            var c = $http.get('/auth/check');
            c.success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            });

        }
    }

}]);
```

The response logs fine in the console, but I cant seem to bind it to a $scope directive:

```
app.controller('BaseController', ['$scope', 'UserService', function($scope, UserService) {

    $scope.loggedIn = UserService.loggedIn();

}]);
```

Returns nothing when I call it as:

```
{{ loggedIn }}
```

...in my view.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$http` service returns a promise. So you would have to write something like

```
app.factory('UserService', ['$http', '$location', function($http, $location) {

    return {
        loggedIn: function() {
            return $http.get('/auth/check');
        }
    }

}]);
```

Controller:

```
UserService.loggedIn().success(function(data) {
    $scope.loggedIn = data;
});
```